# save row in one table to another table using linq

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

You know when you drag and drop a table from the dataSources window onto a usercontrol? Visual studio automatically creates a datacontext (in the view's xaml) to bind the new elements on the page to.This dataContext is set to a collectionViewSource and this collectionViewSource draws it's information from a dataset. The same dataset you took the table from when draging and dropping.

In my scenario this is what it created:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="signupsViewSource" Source="{Binding signups, Source={StaticResource myAppnDataSet}}/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource signupsViewSource}">
    <TextBox x:Name="idTextBox" Text="{Binding id, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="firstnameTextBox" Text="{Binding firstname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="surnameTextBox" Text="{Binding surname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="usernameTextBox" Text="{Binding username, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="passwordTextBox" Text="{Binding password, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

It's supposed to be a very simple signup page that an administrator can use to approve and deny registrations made by simply scrolling through, clicking the approve button or clicking the reject button.

The thing is I'm using the MVVM pattern. This means that the properties the textBoxes above are bound to, are in the collectionViewSource class, which is where my problem begins.

I need to save this same information from the 'signups' table, to the users table.

1. Since the properties the textBoxes are bound to are in the collectionViewSource, Is there any way to fetch their values from there?
2. I looked through the solution explorer and did not find any actual class called signupViewSource. If it doesn't it exist, then how is it referenced and why is it even called a class?
3. Is it a place holder until I create my own collectionViewSource class? Will it be more feasible that way?

What I've tried so far is the following method that is supposed to save the information from the signups table to the users table:

```
private object SaveCurrent_CommandExecute(object param)
{
    myAppEntities context = new myAppEntities();

    myApp.signup Signup = new signup();

    try
    {
        myApp.user User = new Medcare2.user
        {
            firstname = Signup.first,
            surname = Signup.last,
            username = Signup.username,
            password = Signup.password,
        };

        // Persist Changes to database
        context.users.Add(User);
        context.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem with the above method is that it creates a new instance of the signups class I'm saving from, so all the information in the properties I'm grabbing are empty. So I get validation errors. basically. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your selected `Signup` object as the `CommandParameter` on whatever control is invoking the `SaveCurrent` command.  Then you can cast `object param` back to a `Signup` and extract the values from there.

Comment: Correct, if you want to pass the full object then use 'CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"